# Can I study at two universities using a single Short-Term Study visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa

I applied for a Short-Term Study visa recently to study a short course in the UK. I haven't received a decision on my visa application yet but usually the visa is valid for 6 months. Can I stay on in the UK to study another short course at a different university once my course at the first university finishes? Both courses will amount to only 10 weeks.

When I made my visa application, I only declared my intention to study at the first university as the second one had not offered me a place. Now that they have, I am not sure whether I can accept their offer without getting into trouble with my visa (under Paragraph A57D (b)).

Hope this is the right place to ask!

Comment: I've taken a look at the guidance and, admittedly, the wording isn't very clear. Will try to research this a bit....

Comment: I believe the answer is yes based on the provision, ironically perhaps, that allows a change of course under this visa type. As long as your total stay is under the allotted time (assuming they make no specific restriction on your visa), it should be fine. I don't know for sure though, hence I'm putting this as a comment rather than an answer.